# Where can I find Azure service principal credentials for Terraform environment variables?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-active-directory

I have created a variable group ins Azure Devops that I want to use to authenticate Terraform with Azure
[image]

I had this working previously but the credentials have expired. I'm having trouble mapping the values I find in Azure with these four values.

[image]
[image]

I'm reasonably confident that ARM_CLIENT_ID is the "Application (client) ID
The ARM_CLIENT_SECRET is the "Value" from the client secret
ARM_TENANT_ID is the "Directory (tenant) ID"

What should the ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID map to? I've tried mapping it to the Object ID and the Secret ID shown in the two screenshots but neither worked.

What maps to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of `ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID` variable, follow this:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Subscriptions -> Select your subscription -> Overview -> Subscription ID*

[image]

You are right in fetching **values** of other variables like `ARM_CLIENT_ID` and `ARM_TENANT_ID` :

[image]

You can find value of `ARM_CLIENT_SECRET` variable here:

[image]

Comment: Of course ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID maps to my Azure Subscription! I feel silly asking now. Thanks!